# Error when I run npm install -E @okta/okta-react@6.3.0 @okta/okta-auth-js@5.9.1 \ react-dom@17.0.2 react-router-dom@5.3.0

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

When I run

```
npm install -E @okta/okta-react@6.3.0 @okta/okta-auth-js@5.9.1 \ react-dom@17.0.2 react-router-dom@5.3.0
```

It shows this error:

[image]

How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you add the file structure of the project?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your project is named "chat-client" and placed inside your "System32" folder, seems like you are running the `npm` command from a wrong directory (in which case a package.json doesn't exist, i.e, the error). Change to the project directory and then try running the installation command. Hope this helps. Also, you can refer to the following article which provides a few alternatives in case the solution mentioned above doesn’t work:

https://sebhastian.com/npm-err-enoent/

Good luck!